# Getting "LaTeX-Box" Vim plugin  to work with biblatex (biber)

Tags: biblatex, vim

I am using the [LaTeX-Box VIM plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109) for my TeX editing and love it, but I would like to use the omnicomplete freature for Biblatex citations, is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I think you should ask this question at the maintainer site. https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/tree/master/doc

Comment: This looks like a feature request: those are 'off topic' for us.